# .getResource could not find the file in the resouce folder

Tags: java, getresource

This may have been asked a lot but for some reason, my getResource method could not find the file in my resource folder. The file is in `programfolder/resources/images/drag.png`. My getResource code is:

```
SidebarItem.bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(Main.class.getResource("/images/drag.png"));
```

my classpath is:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="resources"/>
```

Whenever I run the main class it always throw an exception because it could find the `drag.png` file. Thanks

Comment: Possibly related: [Loading image resource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9864267)

Comment: And how do you run your class?

Comment: i just run it through my IDE.. should I create an executable jar instead?

Comment: try Main.class.getResource("images/drag.png") without slash at the beginning

Comment: i tried removing the slash before images but it still doesnt work for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
ClassLoader cl = Main.class.getClassLoader();
SidebarItem.bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(cl.getResourceAsStream("images/drag.png"));
```

Comment: still does not work.. but theoretically, given the location of my file and my code it should work right?

Comment: Yes it should. The only thing I could see wrong was `/images/drag.png`.

Comment: You don’t need to give a ‘/‘ there before images.